# How to fill color inside multiple contour line in the matlab

Tags: matlab

I have one image that contains two contour line. I want to fill different colors inside these contour line. How to implement it? This is my code to draw two contour line

```
    function  FillColorContour(Img,phi1,phi2,color1,color2)
        imagesc(uint8(Img),[0 255]),colormap(gray),axis off;axis equal,title('FillColorContour')
        hold on,[c,h1] = contour(phi1,[0 0],'r','linewidth',1); hold off
        hold on,[c,h2] = contour(phi2,[0 0],'r','linewidth',1); hold off
    end
```

To using it. I will call by a command:

```
        Img=imread('peppers.png');
        [Height Wide] = size(Img);
        [xx yy] = meshgrid(1:Wide,1:Height);
        phi1 = (sqrt(((xx - 60).^2 + (yy - 100).^2 )) - 15);
        phi2 = (sqrt(((xx - 100).^2 + (yy - 150).^2 )) - 15);

        FillColorContour(Img,phi1,phi2,'r','b') %Assume'r' is red, 'b' is blue
```

This is before https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll4npg3cmturt4c/contourex.PNG
And this is after run https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqi4rxluxfegxhn/contourexfill.png

Comment: please show example plots of what you have and what you want to obtain. You already had a look at `contourf``?

Comment: I updated what I need. Please check

Comment: +1 for using an example image that comes with Matlab! :-)

Comment: are you sure you need to fill contours? those contours you are using are just circles, so maybe you need a circle fill function?

Comment: @A. Donda: My contour is any contour that means it can be circles,square...In my question. I only make simple question for easy understand. I want to fill color inside contour. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contourc` to compute the contour and `patch` to draw it as a filled area.

Following your (prettified ;) code

```
Img = imread('peppers.png');
[Height, Width] = size(Img);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(1 : Width, 1 : Height);
imagesc(Img,[0 255])
axis off
title('FillColorContour')
phi1 = (sqrt(((xx - 60).^2 + (yy - 100).^2 )) - 15);
```

compute the contour

```
cont = contourc(phi1, [0 0])';
cont = cont(2 : end, :);       % first line contains contour level and number of points; skip
```

and draw it as a "patch":

```
patch(cont(:, 1), cont(:, 2), 'r', 'EdgeColor', 'w')
```

You can choose the fill color and the edge color separately; I used red and white.

Result:

[image: filled contour]

For `phi2` you of course need simply the analogous code.

Comment: Good demonstration of `contourc` and `patch`.

Comment: @A. Donda: How about if I have two circles of one object. I want to fill same red corlor into these circles. How to do it?Assume that these circles don't connect together. Thank you

Comment: @user3336190, just repeat the procedure, starting from `phi1 = …` to `patch(…`.