# MATLAB Fill area between two contour plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour, fill

I have two contour plots and I want to be able to fill from one contour in one image to the same height contour in the other.

[image]

In the plot you can see two lines of each color - these are the lines I want to fill between, with the same color as the lines (though preferably translucent). The code for these are as follows

```
test = repmat(repelem(0:6,2),10,1);
test1 = test(:,2:end-1);
test2 = test(:,1:end-2);
contour(test1,1:5);
hold on;
contour(test2,1:5);
```

I did think that maybe I could create another image that has the desired height at each bin and do some kind of `contourf`, but that could be a problem if in future the lines cross over, which they may well do. In that case, I'd like the area they cross to be a combination of the colors that are crossing over.

Comment: I have edited it to a generic example that anyone should be able to reproduce :)

Comment: There are several similar questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245626/matlab-filling-in-the-area-between-two-sets-of-data-lines-in-one-figure), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698679/shading-between-vertical-lines-in-matlab), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366120/how-to-fill-color-inside-multiple-contour-line-in-the-matlab), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662310/matlab-filled-contour-plot-with-imcontour) (that's all I had room for in a comment). Are none of these applicable to your situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shading between vertical lines in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698679/shading-between-vertical-lines-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try using ```fill``?

```matlab
% test values
col = 'g';
x1=[6 6 6];y1=[1 5 10]; x2= [7 7 7];

x2 = [x1, fliplr(x2)];
inBetween = [y1, fliplr(y1)];
fill(x2, inBetween, col);
```